# Does first strike damage occur before normal damage?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When I attack with a first strike creature, does it deal combat damage before normal combat damage is dealt?

Specifically, if I attack with [Drana, Liberator of Malakir](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDrana%2c%20Liberator%20of%20Malakir%5d) (has first strike and "Whenever Drana, Liberator of Malakir deals combat damage to a player, put a +1/+1 counter on each attacking creature you control.") and 5 other creatures with no counters on them, do I deal damage equal to the creatures' total power or damage equal to the creatures' total power + 5?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yup, that's one of the reasons Drana's powerful - she can pump up your other attackers in time to help them deal more damage. The point of first strike is that it happens first!

Here's how combat plays out, assuming you attack with Drana, your opponent doesn't block her, and nothing weird happens:

- First Combat Damage Step

  - Drana and all other creatures with First Strike or Double Strike deal damage. Drana will deal 2 damage to your opponent, unless you've pumped her up somehow.
  - Drana's ability triggers, then presumably resolves, placing a +1/+1 counter on each of your attacking creatures, including Drana.
- Second ("regular") Combat Damage Step

  - All of your creatures without First Strike (including those with Double Strike) deal damage equal to their power, including the +1 from the counters they just got.

There are rulings [on the Gatherer page for Drana](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=401861) to this effect:

> Drana’s last ability triggers after combat damage has been dealt, so only attacking creatures that survive the combat damage step in which Drana deals combat damage will have +1/+1 counters put on them.
>
> The +1/+1 counter won’t change how much damage Drana or any other attacking creature with first strike or double strike deals during that combat damage step. However, the +1/+1 counters that are put on attacking creatures without first strike will affect the damage those creatures deal during the regular combat damage step.

Comment: It's worth noting that in a tournament setting, it's a good idea to explicitly declare the 'first damage combat step' and the relevant Drana trigger.

Comment: Also technically the regular combat step is 'creatures that didn't deal damage in the first strike step', not 'creatures without first strike'. So you can't use granting FS after the FS step as a pseudo-fog, and removing it after the FS step as pseudo-double strike

Comment: @diego Okay, that might be a bit beyond the scope of the question, but I avoided being technically wrong in that corner case too.

Comment: @Cronax I mean... I guess? I don't really know how necessary it is to add "be sure to declare your triggers" to every question involving a triggered ability, or "be sure to do the two damage steps separately" to every question involving first strike.

Comment: @Jefromi hence why I made it a comment rather than an edit.

Comment: @Cronax My point wasn't about comment vs edit, but just whether it needs to be noted. There are hundreds of questions involving triggered abilities here, so commenting on each of them (or one or more answers to each) seems a bit much.

Comment: I think the comment has value in this case because it concerns an unusual situation which many opponents won't immediately grasp. Explicitly declaring all the steps and triggers will help your opponent to understand exactly what's happening and why things work as they do. If you shortcut things in this case, many people will need a lot more time to grasp that the trigger occurs before the other creatures attack, so I feel it's in everyone's interest. You always have to announce triggers, but there's a bigger return than usual here.

Comment: @Jefromi  "Drana (and all other creatures with First Strike or Double Strike) deal damage to your opponent."  I am not sure I understand why all other creatures with FS or DS will deal damage to the opponent. What if, unlike Drana, they are blocked?

Comment: @uncoder Yes, of course if they're blocked they'll deal damage to the creatures that blocked them. Edited to avoid implying otherwise.

Comment: @diego The result is correct, but rather than "having dealt damage" it's about whether they had first strike at the time of the first strike combat step. My 0/5 first strike won't get a counter from Drana and then hit during the regular combat step just because it didn't deal damage.

Comment: Okay, I just added "assuming nothing weird happens." The point here is to describe a normal combat phase with Drama and some other creatures, not to cover every corner case.

Comment: @Jefromi You could use this wording from the comprehensive rules, as it covers all of those corner cases: *"Creatures that had neither first strike nor double strike as the first combat damage step began [...]"*

Comment: @Rainbolt In order to make that actually correct for double strike you need the next clause too: "...neither first strike nor double strike as the first combat damage step began, *as well as the remaining attackers and blockers that currently have double strike* ..." which seems awfully wordy for this answer. I'm generally okay with "nothing weird happens" as an assumption, especially when it allows more simply addressing the actual question.

Comment: @Cronax There's a balance between always being explicit and step by step in Magic and not making a game drag on, short cutting is a big part of that. At a tournament setting (above regular REL at least) you should expect your opponent to be able to follow short cuts, or if they disagree to raise the issue, particularly when it comes to mandatory triggers.

Comment: @Andrew You don't have to spend minutes in each step, but by shortcutting too much you can deprive the opponent of the ability to respond. Additionally, I'd say that before you start shortcutting, you should explicitly walk through all the steps in the process once. After that, you can announce that you're going to shortcut that process in future iterations.